# how to write a unit test for controller action with promises in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a ember js controller with the following action that takes a model.
How do I write a unit test to test the action which returns a promise?
    deleteUser(model) 
    {
          model.destroyRecord().then(() => this.transitionToRoute('posts'));
    }

Answer (score 0):

The wait() function sounds like what you want here.  Not sure it works with promises, as it does not mention promises in this part of the documentation.  Might want to give it a shot anyway.

From the Ember docs (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/testing/testing-components/):

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import wait from 'ember-test-helpers/wait';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('delayed-typeahead', 'Integration | Component | delayed typeahead', {
  integration: true
});

const stubResults = [
  { name: 'result 1' },
  { name: 'result 2' }
];

test('should render results after typing a term', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(2);

  this.set('results', []);
  this.set('fetchResults', (value) => {
    assert.equal(value, 'test', 'fetch closure action called with search value');
    this.set('results', stubResults);
  });

  this.render(hbs`{{delayed-typeahead fetchResults=fetchResults results=results}}`);
  this.$('input').val('test');
  this.$('input').trigger('keyup');

  return wait().then(() => {
    assert.equal(this.$('.result').length, 2, 'two results rendered');
  });

});
```

EDIT: The example above is from integration tests... not sure this is what you have in mind.  Note, there is also the andThen helper which you may want to look into.  Perhaps give us some more information regarding what you have in mind?